# Batch Find and Copy Lines

Tags: batch-file, copy, find, lines

I need to strip a part of a text file and write it to another one. The stripped text file should be saved as well.

Before:

```
Original.txt = "<xml><something>values</something><script>TEXT-TO-DELETE</script></xml>"
```

After:

```
Original.txt = "<xml><something>values</something><script></script></xml>"

Original_script.txt = "TEXT-TO-DELETE"
```

..
this is a multi-line file, so the script section is spanning many lines.

I tried from scripts that were posted, but can never understand the syntax.

```
"@echo off & setlocal 
set "Data=D:\Original.txt" 
set "Bak=%Data%.bak" 
move "%Data%" "%Bak%" 
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%Bak%") do set "LINE=%%i" & call :ProcessLine 
REM del "%Bak%" 
goto :eof 
:ProcessLine 
echo %LINE%>>"%Data%"
echo %LINE%|findstr /b "<script>">nul || goto :eof 
goto :eof"
```

This should be for windows computers .. (newer OS support)

EDIT: since i cannot answer on my own thread, I do it here:

Thanks for the answer.
Unfortunately I don't want to use shareware for this.
I am parsing in another language, I just need to strip this.

This is a ridiculous 3-liner:

```
file={"p1.txt","p2.txt","p1.txt"}
find={"<search>","</search>,"<xml>"}
count=1
foreachline in file[count] print line to file[count]
if find[count] in line then count++
```

or similar. If there wouldn't be 1000 ways/styles of scripting, I could figure this myself. Just thought some crack would give it a minute.

Comment: you'll have to be more precise with the contents of your files. An example would be best.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about which programming or scripting language you want to use, please? And on which operating system?

Comment: this should be as general as possible. i have win7 64bit. should be dos-type batch script.
UPDATED OP!!!

Comment: This is your first BAT script, I assume. To grasp its syntax, begin with a short tutorial. Google for "windows batch tutorial", read and start studying. Then come back with your questions, we'll be glad to answer.

Comment: To avoid being too error prone concerning special characters and such, I could not get any *dos-type batch script* (let alone a 3-liner) to easily perform such multi-line XML element parsing of an XML document without a little help like i.e. from the tool I mentioned and linked to. It has a free Community Edition that does not require a license key code and may be used royalty-free, and it can be used on both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows. It's your call…

Answer (score 1):

I think an XSLT processor with a CLI is the most appropriate tool here. [AltovaXML2011](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) is the one I use most frequently now.

The script can then be something like this, to extract the contents of the `script` elements to your Original_script file, and then update your original file:

```
@echo off
set orig="D:\Original.txt"
set script="D:\Original_script.txt"
set backup="D:\Original_backup.txt"
set xsltprocessor="D:\AltovaXML.exe"
move %orig% %backup%
::extract scripts
%xsltprocessor% -xslt1 "D:\ExtractScripts.xslt" -in %backup% -out %script%
::update original
%xsltprocessor% -xslt1 "D:\UpdateOriginal.xslt" -in %backup% -out %orig%
::del %backup%
```

With ExtractScripts.xslt looking like this, it extracts the contents of all `script` elements (adding newlines):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//script"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//script">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With UpdateOriginal.xslt looking like this, it just copies the entire original file but leaves out the contents of all `script` elements (already separately extracted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//script">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can choose to keep or delete the backup file afterwards.